# AES EAX encryption/decryption - openpgpjs

Tags: javascript, encryption

I'm trying to update OpenPGP JS  from 4.10.1 to the latest. I tried to go through the documentation but couldn't find the replacement of EAX decryption. The tests folder directly imports the EAX module to test ([as used here](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/blob/main/test/crypto/eax.js#L106)) however on production env, the EAX cannot be imported like that. Here is what I was doing before:

```js
const eax = await window.openpgp.crypto.eax(cipher, key);
let result = await eax.decrypt(encryptedData, nonce, header);
```

How can I decrypt the same using latest version 5.3?